# Ipa file size issue

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ipa

I'm new in **IOS** development. I got problem with my `.ipa` file. I don't use any pod library, and my assets folder size is `5.6 MB`. But when I export my `.ipa` file , it becomes `66 MB`. How can I decrease the size of my `.ipa` file? I imported only `SWRevealController` class. It's a simple app (Also I use 6 `NavigationController` classes). Is it normal? How can I fix that?

Comment: ipa size is not the same as the size in the App Store. So, I think you should ignore that "error" for now.

Comment: That 60MB came from Swift Lib. No worries,, App store it will be less.

Answer (score 4):

.ipa file size is not your application size, it is total size of all your app architectures. When you can change your architectures, the size will decreases.

If you want to find out the size of each architecture, you can change your target device when you export application for AD-HOC or Development.

Answer (score 2):

Yes thats absolutely normal. App thining is done at the app store level. Whenever you create .ipa file it consists of all the configurations needed for all the devices it supports. But whenever a user will download the app from the store he/she will get app size of lesser size , as only the relevant config would have been installed.

Answer (score 0):

If you know that the issue is at the assets catalog file, try to unpack it with a tool like [AssetCatalogTinkerer](https://github.com/insidegui/AssetCatalogTinkerer) and see whether there is an oversized asset. It is possible that an optimized asset is larger than the original, in this case you'll have to tinker around the asset.

It is also important to understand that it is expected to have a different size of an archive, even the one thinned for a specific device, and download size when uploaded to the App Store. This is caused by additional encryption at the App Store and usually affects the executable part. You can find some basic tips at [Technical Q&A QA1795 Reducing the size of my App](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1795/_index.html), it also explains how you can check the real expected download size.